# Add textbox on every page in the book

Tags: text, box

I want to put the textbox in the right of every odd page, and left of every even page. I don't know how to do that. This is my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{ONE}
    \noindent\fbox{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{%
            \rotatebox{270}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Please don't copy and sell this book.}}}
        }%
    }
    \section{ABC}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 

\newpage
\section{DEF}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
\end{document}
```

This code give me
[image]

I want the result as below

[image]

[image]

How to do that?

> Now I want to add the rose picture in center of every page with opacity 0.2. I can't give the picture with different opacity. How to do that?
>   [image]

Comment: Ask another question. This one is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joining forces of tikz and background package lead to this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\backgroundsetup%
{   angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    scale=1,
    contents=%
    {
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{%
       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[draw=black,text=blue,rotate=-90, above=1cm, text width=\textheight, align=center,font=\bfseries, inner sep=0.3cm] at (current page text area.east) {Please don't copy and sell this book.};          
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }{
             \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                  \node[draw=black,text=blue,rotate=90, above=1cm, text width=\textheight,align=center,font=\bfseries, inner sep=0.3cm] at (current page text area.west) {Please don't copy and sell this book.};       
              \end{tikzpicture}
       }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{ONE}
    \section{ABC}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 

\newpage
\section{DEF}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, nigel. I will try it.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I have additional question.

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya Ask another question. This one is solved.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple with `eso-pic` and `ifoddpage`. Note I didn't retain the frames, but it's easy to add them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic, ifoddpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage
\AtPageLowerLeft{\hspace*{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2.4cm}
\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\paperheight]{\textcolor{SteelBlue!70}{\small\textbf{Please don't copy and sell this book.}}}}}%
\else\AtPageUpperLeft{\hspace*{1.8cm} \rotatebox{-90}{\makebox[\paperheight]{\textcolor{SteelBlue!70}{\small\textbf{Please don't copy and sell this book.}}}}}\fi%
}%

\begin{document}
    \chapter{ONE}

    \section{ABC}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test

\newpage
\section{DEF}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Bernard. I will try it.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I have additional question.

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya Ask another question. This one is solved.